# Custom sorting query in KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, knppaginator

I would like to sort items in KnpPaginatorBundle by a custom callback. Is it possible to hook to the Walker somehow?

I mean I want to sort by invoice number which should be something like:

```
3/5/2020
2/5/2020
1/5/2020 
3/4/2020
2/4/2020
```

instead of

```
3/5/2020
3/4/2020
2/5/2020
2/4/2020
1/5/2020
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting your results before sending them to paginator? For example, if you do a repository call, you can sort there or after you get your results and have them in an array or Collection and sort then, before calling `paginate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go this way. Try to make filter before paginate and done result use in pagination